# how to write path of an executable in case of windows when application name has versions appened to it

Tags: python, windows

I am totally new to parsing XML, I am making an app that reads the configuration from an xml file from disk , if its not found it creates a config file, but based on system wether it is *nix or windows I want to generate a configuration file XML, in linux its easy, but for windows I'd have to browse the exe file , so in windows case how should I handle call to `makeConfFile()` I have made it as public function, so if someone uses the API call to this method can happen from anwhere apart from that

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom 
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement

def getConfFilePath():
    confFilePath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'moveEditor.conf')
    if os.path.isfile(confFilePath):
    return confFile
    else:
    # make a configuration xml file at this path
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        return confFilePath if makeConfFile(confFilePath) else raise IOError("Configuration file not found.")
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        # How to do this part

def makeConfFile(filePath, imageMagic=None, ffmpeg=None):
    root = Element('tools')
    # set defaults on *nix
    ffmpeg = ffmpeg if ffmpeg else 'ffmpeg'
    imageMagic = imageMagic if imageMagic else 'convert'

    ffmpeg_child = SubElement(root, 'ffmpeg', value=ffmpeg)
    imageMagic_child = SubElement(root, 'imageMagic', value=imageMagic)
    rough_string = ET.tostring(root, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    data = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    try:
    with open(filePath, 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(data)
    except IOError, err:
    print err
    return
    return True


tree = ET.parse(getConfFilePath())
elem = tree.getroot()


FFMPEG_BINARY = elem[0].attrib['value']
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = elem[1].attrib['value']
```

any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the information you need using Python's **os** module. This should work:

```
home = os.getenv('USERPROFILE') or os.getenv('HOME')
```

I found this handy trick here:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820043

Comment: I am asking question w.r.t. MS Windows, where on Windows in program files folder softwares folders have version appened to them so how to located the latest or what is in use  or which one to use if multiple versions !!

Comment: Are you asking where your script is running from? That's a bit different. One way to get that location is `script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath( __file__ ))`

Comment: no, I am asking for all the softwares being installed on windows not the python script, intact this python script has to search for the exe file however since I am not a windows user I don't know what strategy does window uses for versions of software rather than version appended to software in program files folder.

Comment: On Windows, you can find most of that information in the Windows Registry, assuming the software can be uninstalled. On Windows XP, it was stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, but I'm guessing Windows 7/8 stores the same information in the same location or one that is very similar. I wrote a tutorial on the topic that uses Python's `_winreg` module: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/03/finding-installed-software-using-python/